# Why do supernatural titles contain the word 'Code'?

Tags: tropes

A lot of series about supernatural powers seem to contain the word 'Code' in the title. For example,

- Code Geass
- Code:Breaker
- Code:Realise
- Code-E

Why is there a trend like this among anime titles? What does this signify, if any?

Comment: I seem to see two different questions here. Are you asking why it is a trend to use the word Code: <something> on anime titles or what it means for each anime? Because as far as I know, the word 'code' refers to different things depending on the anime. There is no one definition of 'code' for all the anime that uses it in their titles...

Comment: Yes. To clarify: why is there that trend?

Comment: Thanks for the help clarifying my question.

Comment: Code Geass (2006), Code-E (2007), Code:Breaker (2008), Code:Realize (2017). I'd safely take out Realize from the list since it's so long apart from the others to justify a "trend".